# Change decimal place of a number

Tags: python, math

I am calling an API and it returns a number, for example:

`1.0180270269977621e+29`

For some reason the decimal point is in the wrong position.

I am simply removing the 'e+29' part. The number should really be: `101802.70269977621`. I can convert it by multiplying it by 100000. However, when the API returns something like: `9.9182376273562`, the real value should be: `99182.376273562` so multiplying it by 100000 will result in the wrong number (991823.76273562 is wrong), so here I need to multiply it by 10000.

I am trying to find a good way of converting it to always get the real value. How can i do this? Can I use the Math module?

Comment: So what should happen when it is `1.23456e10`, or `1.23456e15`, or `1.23456e20`, or any other magnitude? What is the general *rule* you want to apply?

Comment: Sounds like you need to talk to whoever created this API.

Comment: *"it returns a number ... I am simply removing the 'e+29' part"*: then you don't receive a number... Looks like you receive a string then.

Comment: The only way i check the real value is by going to another webpage where the true value is displayed correctly. but the API returns it with the wrong decimals.

Comment: You definitely need to talk to the API owner if they're sending bad data

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

I should not remove the 'e+29' part.

```
n = 1.0283240219674682e+29
expanded = f'{n:.8f}'
exp = int(expanded.split(".")[0])
e = exp/1000000000000000000000000
print(round(float(e), 2))
```